# Regex to remove everything except letters and remove multiple spaces

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to make a single regex to remove everything except:

1. letters
2. apostrophe's
3. single spaces

I tried `([^\\p{L} ']+` with a Lookbehind for the extra spaces `(?<=\\s)\\s+`.  Each works in isolation:

```
gsub("(?<=\\s)\\s+", "", "I like 56 dogs that's him55.", perl = TRUE)
## [1] "I like 56 dogs that's him55."

gsub("[^\\p{L} ']+", "", "I like 56 dogs that's him55.", perl = TRUE)
## [1] "I like  dogs that's him"
```

But when I use or (`|`) to connect them:

```
gsub("((?<=\\s)\\s+)|([^\\p{L} ']+)", "", "I like 56 dogs that's him55.", perl = TRUE)
```

This returns:

```
[1] "I like  dogs that's him"
```

I'd like it to remove the multiple extra space (between like & dogs) like:

```
[1] "I like dogs that's him"
```

How can I use one regex to remove everything except  letters, apostrophes and extra spaces?

Comment: I dont think this can be done in single replacement.. you will need atleast two replacements.

Comment: @rawr can you re-add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like issue comes from having space in you regex which turns each number into space, code bellow worked fine for me:

```
gsub("[^\\p{L}']+", " ", "I like 56 dogs that's him55.", perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following if you're trying to do this in one call:

```
gsub("[^\\pL' ]+\\h+(?=\\h)|\\h+(?=[^\\pL' ]+)|[^\\pL' ]+", "", x, perl=T)
# [1] "I like dogs that's him"
```

Here is another way you could approach this if you desire which is more efficient IMO.

```
x <- "I like 56 dogs that's him55."
r <- gsub("[^\\pL' ]+", '', x, perl=T)
paste(strsplit(r, '\\s+')[[1]], collapse = ' ')
# [1] "I like dogs that's him"
```